# Control placement in manipulate environments

Tags: manipulate, slider

Is it possible to have sliders and such appear *centered* on the top or bottom of the panel? The `ControlPlacement` options only include `Top`, `Bottom`, `Left`, and `Right`, but the `Top` placement gives me left-aligned controls, while I want them centered. How do I achieve this?

Comment: You can put there whatever you want, is that enough?: [Overlaying a Plot within a Manipulate Control Panel](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40752/5478).

Comment: No, unless I misunderstand, it's the slider itself the placement of which I want more control over. From the answer below it looks like there's no simple way to achieve this, other than kludges... :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Control Image Size` control is provided just to demonstrate the approximate automatic centering of the `n` control at varying image sizes

```
Manipulate[
 Style[N[Pi, n], Small],
 Column[{
   Control[{{cis, 300, "Control Image Size"}, 100, 500, 50,
     Appearance -> "Labeled"}]},
  ItemSize -> 75,
  Alignment -> Center],
 Column[{
   Control[{{n, 100}, 10^2, 10^4, 10^2,
     Appearance -> "Labeled",
     ImageSize -> cis}]},
  ItemSize -> 75,
  Alignment -> Center],
 AppearanceElements -> None,
 ContentSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, that helps, thanks!

Comment: I don't really get it... When you change `ItemSize->75` to any other value, e.g. `50`, it's not centered anymore. So how is this different from finding a value for `Spacer` in my answer?

Comment: @corey979 - I see the difference as the ability to change the `ImageSize` for the control for `n` without changing its column's `ItemSize`

Answer (score 0):

This is a way for a workaround:

```
Manipulate[
 Style[N[Pi, n], Small], {{n, 100, Row[{Spacer[175], "n"}]}, 100, 
  10000, 100, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Automatic}, 
 AppearanceElements -> None, ContentSize -> 600]
```

Unfortunately you have to set the argument of `Spacer[175]` by trial and error; also playing with `ContentSize -> 600` and `ImageSize -> Automatic` might be required for the window to have nice proportions.

Comment: Hmm, too bad. I guess I'll have to rethink the design I have in mind...