# Problem controlling layout of Manipulate-generated GUI

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

For example:

```
Manipulate[
 With[{value = a}, 
  Plot[Sin[value x], {x, 0, 10},
       ImageSize -> Small,
       PlotLegends -> "AllExpressions"]
 ],
 {a, 1, 2}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

Below I show two snapshots of the same GUI, for two different positions of the slider:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I have two (simple?) questions regarding this example:

1. How can I center the slider vertically (while still keeping it to the left of the plot)?
2. How can I keep the width of the GUI fixed, irrespective of the width of the legend's text (while still keeping the legend to the right of the plot)?

Comment: 1. you can put there whatever you want: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40752/5478

Comment: 2. add `ContentSize -> 350` as an option to `Manipulate`.

Comment: You might want to consider a [`VerticalSlider`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VerticalSlider.html): `{a, 1, 2, 0.01, ControlType -> VerticalSlider, Appearance -> "Labeled"}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
  With[{value = a}, 
   Plot[Sin[value x], {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> Small, 
    PlotLegends -> "AllExpressions"]], 
  Column[{Control[{{a, 1}, 1, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]}, 
   ItemSize -> {Automatic, 8}],
 ControlPlacement -> Left, ContentSize -> 350]
```

[image]